# Plot completely without borders

Tags: r, plot

I set up a nice plot with a transparent superimposed scatterplot on a png image file. I want my plot window and my pdf output to be of the exact same size as my png- 962x745.

However, even after turning off axes, annotations and frames, R still leaves a border around the image.

This can be shown with an easy example: This plot shows two dots, which should be at the outermost ends of the plot. But they aren't:

```
plot(rbind(c(1,745),c(962,1)),bty ="n",axes=F,frame.plot=F, xaxt='n', ann=FALSE, yaxt='n', asp=745/962)
```

And together with the PDF device:

```
pdf(width=10.02,height=7.76)
par(mar=rep(0, 4),mai=rep(0, 4), xpd = NA) 
plot(rbind(c(1,745),c(962,1)),bty ="n",axes=F,frame.plot=F, xaxt='n', ann=FALSE, yaxt='n', asp=745/962)
dev.off()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also use `grid` graphics to avoid those default axes, etc.

```
library(jpeg)
library(grid)

d = data.frame(x=rnorm(100, 10), y=rnorm(100, -100))
utils::download.file("http://i.imgur.com/5MexD.jpg", "img.jpg")
img = readJPEG("img.jpg")


w <- convertUnit(unit(ncol(img),"pt"), "in", value=TRUE)
h <- convertUnit(unit(nrow(img),"pt"), "in", value=TRUE)

dev.new(width=w, height=h)    
grid.raster(img, width=unit(1,"npc"), height=unit(1,"npc"))

 v = dataViewport(xData=d$x, yData=d$y)
 grid.points(d$x,d$y, default.units="native", vp=v, 
             gp=gpar(col="white"), pch=8)
```

[image]

Comment: baptiste: interesting approach, I will play with that

Comment: ok, this solution is perfect .... but how does this points command convert to grid points points(xy, col="#ff000012", pch=16,cex=1) ... ok, got it, those parameters go into gpar

Answer (score 6):

Try:

```
par(mar=rep(0, 4), xpd = NA) 
plot(rbind(c(1,745),c(962,1)),bty ="n",axes=F,frame.plot=F, xaxt='n', ann=FALSE, yaxt='n', asp=745/962)
```

Comment: @user1216731 Different units, same thing, I believe. `mai` is in inches, `mar` is in lines.

Comment: I tried mar option but it doesnt work :(. would it be possible to answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29828821/r-raster-avoid-white-space-when-plotting?

Answer (score 6):

here is the best solution. Just set axes = 0

```
plot(1:10, axes = 0)
```

Comment: easiest solution to date

Answer (score 3):

You have to set the margins:

```
par(mar=c(0,0,0,0))
```

Comment: I tried mar option but it doesnt work :(. would it be possible to answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29828821/r-raster-avoid-white-space-when-plotting?

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling a lot with this problem and `box = FALSE` worked for me.

example:

```js
img_03 = na.omit(img_02)

png(file = paste("ndvi",".png",sep=""), bg = "transparent")

plot(img_03,
  legend=FALSE,
  axes = 0,
  frame.plot=0,
  box = FALSE,
  useRaster=0,
  col = hcl.colors(100, "RdYlGn")
)

dev.off()
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stackoverflow :)
It would be great if you could add a short running example with a bit more context.

Comment: img_03 = na.omit(img_02)
png(file = paste("ndvi",".png",sep=""), bg = "transparent")
plot(img_03,legend=FALSE,axes = 0,frame.plot=0, box = FALSE,useRaster=0,col = hcl.colors(100, "RdYlGn"))
dev.off()

Comment: You can also edit your answer and include what you wrote while also wrapping it into code ticks (`)