# R raster avoid white space when plotting

Tags: r, image, plot, raster

I have an image and i want to plot only 100*100 square with left hand bottom corner at 0,0.
when i use below commands. Why do i get a white space around my cropped image?
how can i avoid it and ensure that I get exact 100*100 image?

If you want to repeat my example, you can use any image on line 1 (provided that the image is bigger than 100*100 pixels)

```
r <- raster("C:/Users/nnnn/Desktop/geo.jpg")
vector= getValues(r)
plot(r)
r


par(mar=c(0,0,0,0))
par(oma=c(0,0,0,0))
par(mai=c(0,0,0,0))
par(omi=c(0,0,0,0))
plot(r,xlim=c(0,100),ylim=c(0,100),legend=FALSE,axes=FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: Do you want the image to maintain its aspect ratio (i.e. remain a square) even when you resize the window it's plotted in? Or are you asking about how to plot it to another non-interactive device (e.g. `pdf`, `png`, `bmp`, etc.)

Comment: i want to save it as a square (cropped size) as a PNG file

Comment: @JoshO'Brien would it be possible to provide suggestions regarding how I should change mar, mai, oma, omi options so that when i save the cropped image as png I don't get any white margins?

Comment: I think your issue is that the default behaviour which "fills" the device, doesn't then respect the xlim/ylim for a given aspect ratio. I don't know an easy way, but judicious use of par(fig) can get you this.

Comment: @mdsumner would it be possible to suggest how i can use par(fig)?

Comment: @mdsumner -- Also sounds like the OP wants to know how to precisely clip out/select/subset the lower left 100x100 cell region as a raster. Is there a single function to do that? (I know one could crop it with an `Extent` object (whose component values are coordinates), and get the values with `getValuesBlock`, given row, nrows, col, and ncols. Is there any way to crop (and get a raster as the return value) with row/column indices like those passed to `getValuesBlock()`?)

Comment: @JoshO'Brien thanks for understanding my question

Comment: getting a png or jpeg image is very imp

Comment: would it be possible to modify your answer/provide code which achives the objective?

Comment: like this: https://github.com/mdsumner/talks/blob/master/KGG375_2014-10-10/aspectplot.R   page 13ish is the answer I was on about in dash2.html in that project

Comment: For the 'getting a png' part, just uncomment the lines beginning `png` and `dev.off` in my answer (and comment out the line beginning `dev.new`). The complete answer now shows how to both extract a block of cells in the raster's lower left corner, and to plot them so that they fill a properly sized device.

Answer (score 1):

Aspect ratios are normally maintained for maps. You can use width/height when plotting to a file. You can resize the standard device manually, but you can also do this:

```
library(raster)
r <- raster(nrow=240, ncol=320)
values(r) <- 1:ncell(r)
dev.new(height=0.91*nrow(r)/50, width=1.09*ncol(r)/50)
plot(r, legend=FALSE)
```

Comment: would it be possible to modify/suggest changes to code in my original question? I want to crop the image

Comment: Well, it works nicely, I'd say. I made some minor adjustments. Note that height and width are in inches. The device size is not entirely proportional to the plotted raster, hence some empirical adjustments.

Comment: Another thing to consider is to do plot(..., axes=FALSE, box=FALSE) and then axis(1), axis(2) (with additional arguments)

Comment: would it be possible to post adjustments that you made? also how do i convert inches to pixels?

Comment: also please add lines to create a PNG file from the cropped image

Answer (score 0):

Here's my best shot:

```
library(raster)

## An example raster
logo <- raster(system.file("external/rlogo.grd", package="raster")) 

## Clip out the lower-left 50*100 pixel rectangle as a new raster 'r'
cropWithRowCol <- function(r, rows, cols) {
    cc <- cellFromRowColCombine(r, rownr=rows, colnr=cols)
    crop(r, rasterFromCells(r, cc, values=FALSE))
}
r <- cropWithRowCol(logo, nrow(logo) - 49:0, 1:100)


## Extract multipliers used to appropriately size the selected device
w <- ncol(r)/max(dim(r))
h <- nrow(r)/max(dim(r))

## Set up appropriately sized device with no borders and required coordinate system    
## png("eg.png", width=480*w, height=480*h)
dev.new(width=5*w, height=5*h)
plot.new()
par(mar=c(0,0,0,0), oma=c(0,0,0,0))
plot.window(xlim=extent(r)[1:2], ylim=extent(r)[3:4], xaxs="i",yaxs="i")

## Finally, plot the (sub-)raster to it
plot(r, axes=FALSE, legend=FALSE, add=TRUE)
## dev.off()
```

(Please remember that, in an interactively resizable device, changing the device's size will mess up the plotted map's aspect ratio.)

[image]

Comment: would it be possible to suggest changes that i should make to my code in the original question?

Comment: how would i select multipliers w and h in my case?

Comment: Select them by using the code I supplied, i.e. `w <- ncol(r)/max(dim(r))` etc. on your own raster `r`. Or am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: i am a bit confused. Why do we need w and h? it seems that they come from original image/photo. But i want to cut a part of that photo and print it. Lets say my photo A is 2000*450 pixels and photo B is 230*211 pixels. In both cases i want bottom left hand square of size 100*100. So why would l need w and h? they will be different for both photos even though output that i want (100*100 square) is same in the both cases

Comment: any solution that you can recommend?

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly this problem producing a png.
The way I fixed it was by adjusting the wid parameter in the code below.

```
scale=5
png(file=outfile,width=wid*scale,height=800*scale,res=72*scale)
```

Answer (score -1):

Change the aspect ratio:

```
plot(r, asp=1)
```