# PNG image without border/frame in R?

Tags: r, image

I am trying to produce a png file that has no black frame around. I know how it works with the plot command, but I cannot find any solution using png() or image(). These are the command lines of concern:

```
png(filename = paste(outDir,"/PRCP",yy0,mm0,dd0,"+",sprintf("%03.0f",(lt*6)),"h_temp.png",sep=""), width = (dPm[2]), height = (dPm[1]), bg = "transparent")
par(mai=c(0,0,0,0))
image(Dem[,dPm[1]:1],col=grey((13:0)/15),useRaster = TRUE, add = FALSE,zlim=range(Dem,na.rm=TRUE))
dev.off()
```

Has anybody an advice?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Plot completely without borders](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9332170/plot-completely-without-borders)

Comment: So are you looking for something like `frame.plot=FALSE` that will work with `image`?

Comment: You might want to checkout the `ggplot2` package; `geom_raster` will get you plots like you see from `image`, and you can control frame with arguments to `theme`.

Answer (score 0):

ok, after trying many many different options (unsuccessful), I finally found it out.
If you use image(), then you have to put axes=FALSE in order to not get a frame

PS: thanks for all the help offered!